# Delphi - Passing Header values to REST Services

Tags: rest, delphi

I have a REST Service.  By default, the JSON data being returned has all the NULLs eliminated.  This is causing me difficulties, so I have a request header setting that changes the behavior.  The request header I need to add is:
**Accept-Formatting: json-nulls=include**

I have been able to get to work from POSTMAN, using the following format.

[image]

I have not been able to get this to work from my application.
My application has a TRestClient, TRestResponse and TRestRequest.

I have tried adding this as a parameter on both TRestClient and TRestRequest. While the REST service returns the data, the NULL fields are not being displayed, which tells me that my format (or something else relating to the request header) is not correct.  Where and HOW should this be added?
Any thoughts appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me. Did you verify if the `Accept-Formatting` header is actually being sent? Personally, I dislike Embarcadero's REST framework. It is overly complicated to use and quite buggy. I suggest switching to another REST client. Or, just use something like Indy's `TIdHTTP` to send your own REST request manually, then you have full control over it.

Comment: @Remy, - No I haven't.  How do I do that?

Comment: Either sniff the network traffic using a packet sniffer like Wireshark, or have your server log the headers it actually receives

Comment: I had a similar problem supplying a GUID via an Access-Token header and needed to add the poDoNotEncode option, then it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Try directly call from Tools > Rest debugger, if all working copy/paste component to your project and try manuly change some parameter.

Example:

[image]

Comment: You also should set `[poDoNotEncode]` option for the Authorization header, otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you, Soon Santos' comment works for me and I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to send the firebase notification programmatically you can try the way I use and it is working for me.

```
{Send a notification to Firebase Messaging.

 @param Titulo Notification title
 @param Mensagem Notification message
 @param Page The page the user will be redirected after the notification is clicked Ex: `/home`}
function EnviarNotificacao(Titulo, Mensagem, Page: string): string;
var
  RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
  RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
  JsonBody, JsonNotification, JsonData, JsonResponse: TJSONObject;
begin
  RESTClient1 := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
  RESTRequest1 := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  RESTResponse1 := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
  RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
  RESTRequest1.Response := RESTResponse1;
  RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Authorization', 'key=AAAd...', pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

  JsonBody := TJSONObject.Create;
  JsonNotification := TJSONObject.Create;
  JsonData := TJSONObject.Create;
  JsonNotification.AddPair('title', Titulo);
  JsonNotification.AddPair('body', Mensagem);
  JsonData.AddPair('click_action', 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK');
  JsonData.AddPair('page', Page);

  JsonBody.AddPair('notification', JsonNotification);
  JsonBody.AddPair('data', JsonData);
  JsonBody.AddPair('to', '/topics/your_topic');

  RESTRequest1.AddBody(JsonBody);
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  JsonResponse := RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
  Result := JsonResponse.ToString;
end;
```

You should also free the `TJSONObject`, I didn't do that because I was in a hurry.